# Retrieving a table cell's text once clicked in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been having some trouble retrieving text of a table cell that is clicked, the only way I can get the event to fire is substituting "tbody td" with

```
$("body").click(function(e) {
```

but this does not return correct data value for cell clicked. Anyone know what I might be doing wrong? I need to create the table using jQuery so it can be dynamically sized based on input given from a form.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selection').submit(function() {
        $(function () {

            var $tbl = $('<table border="1">').attr('id', 'table');
            var $tbody = $('<tbody>').attr('id', 'tableBody');

            for (var i = 0; i < $("#numOfPieces").val(); i++) {
                var trow = $("<tr>"); // New row

                for (var j = 0; j < $("#numOfPieces").val(); j++) {
                    $("<td>")
                            .text('Row : ' + i + ', Col: ' + j)
                            .appendTo(trow); // New data cell
                }
                trow.appendTo($tbody);
            }

            $tbl.append($tbody);
            $('table').remove(); // Remove previously created table
            $('body').append($tbl);
        });
        return false;
    });

    $("tbody td").click(function(e) {
        var currentCellText = $(this).text();
        var LeftCellText = $(this).prev().text();
        alert(currentCellText);
    });
});
```

Comment: What is it doing wrong? For example, if you put as the value the number of each cell, if you click on row 3, column 4 (perhaps that would have a value of 34) is the value 53 (row 5, column 3)?

Comment: The event handler was never being called, as pointed out by steveax in a comment below the element that the listener is attached to needed to exist already on the page hence use `$('body').on('click', 'tbody td' .. `

Comment: @bobbyme01 - I was curious if that was what was happening, which is why I didn't give an answer, I expected his observation was correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your click handler is bound to the EXISTING table. You need to bind it to "any" table. In the document ready function:

```
$('.container').on('click', 'td', function(e) {
  var currentCellText = $(this).text();
  // etc
});
```

Where `.container` is any container wrapper element that's not expected to get destroyed. Make this the closest ancestor you can. If no candidates are available then you can use `body`, but I would avoid going this high up if you can.

The `td` selector can of course be modified to be more specific if need be. If you have a type of table that this behaviour should be present in, forget about IDs and give that type of table a class. Then the `td` just becomes `.someClass td` instead.

You will probably also want to sanitize that your LefCellText even exists before trying to use it. Declaring the variable the way you have it is fine (if there's no such selector, it just becomes undefined) but you don't want to assume that you're going to have the content, you'll want to create a fallback plan.

Comment: +1 for delegating with [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) but I believe the selector must exist when the handler is bound (_"Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on()"_) so you'd want: `$('body').on('click', 'tbody td', function(e) {...`

Comment: Guys you's are brilliant! I had to use `$('body').on('click', 'tbody td' ..` as steveax suggested to handle the event correctly. Thank you both for your help!

Comment: I'd amend that to `$('body').on('click', 'table#table tbody td', function(e) {...` to narrow it down to that specific table although you may want to consider a better `id` value.

Comment: Agreed on the `id` value, also might be faster to pare the selector down to just `'#table td'`, so: `$('body').on('click', '#table td', function(e) {...`

Comment: Good idea, more tables may be added to the page so a more unique id will be used for that particular one, thanks

Comment: Dang it, whoops! You're so right. I'm usually better than that with `.on()` (redface). I usually go through the whole process of recommending "the closest non-destroyed ancestor" and by not putting that verbiage I missed my own sloppiness. So yes, go with the closest non-destroyed element rather than `body` if you can!